# Excel form lost path

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, network-shares, microsoft-excel-2010, path

On my file server, some Excel files lost their path.

For example:

```
=if(A2='\\172.168.1.1\SHARING\LANAIM\Gest_Qual\05__REG\04__Gest\[file1.xlsx]data'!$A2;2;False)
```

What they turned into was:

```
=if(A2='\\172.168.1.1\04__Gest\[file1.xlsx]data'!$A2;2;False)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: the formula has changed? Have you tried looking at the Links in the workbook and change the source of the file there? Or define a name in the workbook and use that for your path, and thus have a definite path defined where you control it.

Comment: Not the formula, only the path. the name does not changed, nor the path. Only the path loses information of destiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Edit** > **Links** command to change all links to external workbooks at once.

Comment: i'm use this to see existe error. but not ressolve my problem. the path lose informacion alone. ty for help